# Need to convert a dictionary which contains two lists into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-structures, dataset

So the dictionary I got is as below:

```
{'a': [[time1, a1], [time2, a2],[time100,a100]], 'b': [[time1, b1], [time2, b2],[time100,b100]], 'c': [[time1, c1], [time2, c2],[time100,c100]]}
```

The first item of every list is time in Unix timestamps and I'd like the time to be every row and columns = ['a','b','c']. Also the second item in every list to be in each of their respected cell.
Expected Results:

```
          a           b          c
time1.    a1.          b1.       c1
time2.    a2.         b2        c2
time100
```

Essentially the time in every list is the same regardless of the key.I want to pick the time out and put the second item in each list to their each respected column.
How does the code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d={'a': [['time1', 'a1'], ['time2', 'a2'],['time100','a100']], 'b': [['time1', 'b1'], ['time2', 'b2'],['time100','b100']], 'c': [['time1', 'c1'], ['time2', 'c2'],['time100','c100']]}
```

try via `DataFrame()` and `apply()` and `reset_index()`:

```
#import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(d).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index(drop=True)
#you can also use agg() in place of apply()
```

Now we will filter out result:

```
c=df.index%2==0 
df=df[~c].set_index(df.loc[c,'a'].values)
#OR
df=df[~c].set_index(df[c]['a'].values)
```

output of `df`:

```
            a       b       c
time1       a1      b1      c1
time2       a2      b2      c2
time100     a100    b100    c100
```

Comment: please see the edited question. I'm really sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Martinesk kindly have updated answer **:)**

Comment: Thank you for your reply!! But this is what it returned: [ True False  True False  True False  True False]. The first lines runs just fine, results as below: 
     a              b                   c
0  time1        time1          time1
1   a1             b1                 c1

Comment: @Martinesk run the whole code not just `c=df.index%2==0 `